# How can I build a standalone MQSeries client under Linux using the C API?

Tags: c, linux, client, ibm-mq

IBM offer an installable MQSeries Client software that allows you to access queue managers on remote hosts. They also offer some C-callable libraries that let you do messaging from a C application.

My problem is that I don't have admin access on the hosts I plan to test-deploy on, and getting an application installed comes with bigtime Enterprise hassle. IBM, meanwhile, acts as if there's no alternative to installing their whole client package. Assuming I'm willing to forgo their support, can I get around this? i.e. is there some set of objects/libraries I can link with to produce a standalone client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From v8.0.0.4 onwards, IBM provides set of libraries as a zip/tar and you don't need to install whole client package. See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q122882_.htm.

But you still need queue manager running somewhere to test your application.

Comment: Thank you, @Shashi! I made a lot of progress today thanks to that download.

Comment: Glad I could help